# what is "isPagingEnabled" in swift UIScrollView?

Tags: swift, xcode

what is "isPagingEnabled" in swift UIScrollView

I tried searching on apple docs but couldn't understand, someone please explain

Answer (score 0):

isPagingEnabled is bool, making it true basically prevents the page from being displayed halfway between the present and next page while scrolling

[click here for visual rep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4QK6.png)